# Ionic 4- Receive Variable Update with BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, ionic4

At home I have a list of products that on click opens the product modal with a button to add to the cart. When you add the amount appears next to the icon. I want to close this mode in app.component to update the icon that is in the footer. I need to update this cart with the modal value that was closed without refresh.

**servico.ts**

```
public totalShop: BehaviorSubject<String>;

 constructor() {
    this.totalShop = new BehaviorSubject('0');       
 }

 setTotalShop(val) {    
    this.totalShop.next(val);    
  }

  clearTotalShop() {
    this.totalShop.next('0');
  }

  getTotalShop(){    
    return this.totalShop.asObservable();
  }
```

**modalProduto.ts**

```
fnShop(){
    quantidade = quantidade +1
    this.servico.setTotalShop(quantidade)
 }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
quantshop;
 subscription: Subscription;

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.subscription = this.servico.getTotalShop().subscribe(val => this.quantshop = val);
   console.log(this.quantshop)
}
```

**app.module**

```
  providers: [servico]
```

**imagem**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use the angular material badge.

You can use the angular async pipe in your html.

```
<mat-icon [matBadge]="global.getTotalShop() | async">icon</mat-icon>
```

You need to make the service public to access it in the html or make another variable in the component.ts you assign the BehaviourSubject.

Comment: Nothing happens, it fetches the default value that zero

Comment: updated the service name, was incorrect .. but still not getting the result